# Encoding problems with Stanford NER. Which encoding should I use?

Tags: java, powershell, encoding, stanford-nlp

I'm having a hard time to find the right encoding for Portuguese so that the result to appear properly. I initially used this command to tag a small sample with my model:

```
PS > java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier ner-model.ser.gz -textFile tweets.txt
```

As an example, one of the phrases is as follows:

> Meus pais na época em que eram casados e minha mãe era viva !. em Praia De Copacabana - Posto 5 .

See the special characters in for example: "época" and "mãe", they turn out like this in the final result:

> Meus/O pais/O na/O ├⌐poca/O em/O que/O eram/O casados/O e/O minha/O m├úe/O era/O viva/O !/O 
>   ./O 
>   em/O Praia/B-LOCATION De/I-LOCATION Copacabana/I-LOCATION -/O Posto/B-LOCATION 5/I-LOCATION ./O

época = ├⌐poca

mãe = m├úe

Not the result expected.

It can also be happening when I train the model which is a serious concern. I tried to use the -encoding flag with various options:

- UTF-8
- iso-8859-15
- iso-8859-1

I generally have success with UTF-8 or iso-8859-1, but this time I having the same result as the one I showed above. 
I made sure that the file is encoded with UTF-8, also tried to export to a file encoding it in UTF-8 as well, with the same result.

I don't know if it has some influence, but I'm using PowerShell to run the commands.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run the following first: `[console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding`; see [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3819#issuecomment-302943793).

Comment: Thank you for the help, it worked perfectly, I had to put a flag for encoding on both sides though, the final command is this: `PS > java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier ner-model.ser.gz -textfile tweets.txt -encoding utf-8  | Out-File resultado3.tsv -Encoding utf8`